# Cannot insert into MySQL via NetBeans

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans

Can someone help me with the problem that I'm having now?

I have a set of question(survey). When the user done the survey, it will insert to my database.

However, right now, when I submit the survey, it doesn't insert the result into my database.

here is my code:

```
  try  {



        //Process - Query from SQL       
  String strSqlnsert = "INSERT INTO Customers (MembershipID, Contact, Email, Address, SurveyStatus, Subscription) VALUES"
             + " ('"+ member_ID + "', " + contact_num + ", '" + email_add + "', '" + mail_add + "' , " + radio_group + "," + receive_info + ")";             



            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/customers", "root", "password");
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSqlnsert);
```

I've also add in the library for the JDBC in the library folder.

Comment: It seems the non numeric values aren't quoted.

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there is no error, just that i can't insert the result

Answer (score 0):

It seems the non numeric values aren't quoted

Instead of

```
" + email_add + ",
```

try

```
'" + email_add + "',
```

In the below insert statement

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ( 5, 'this is a string');
```

the 'this is a string' is wrapped in quotes, because `field2` is of type VARCHAR. `field1` is INT so the value assigned to it (5) doesn't need quoting.

---

The `VALUES` list must be in braces too and again, non numeric values must be quoted:

```
String strSqlnsert = "INSERT INTO Customers (MembershipID, Contact, Email, Address, SurveyStatus, Subscription) VALUES (" + member_ID + ", " + contact_num + ", '" + email_add + "', '" + mail_add + "', '" + radio_group + "', '" + receive_info + "')";
```

Comment: The problem is still that... You need to sort out quoting issues.

Comment: my radiogroup && receiveInfo is int, whereas memberid is varchar..

is it like this?

  String strSqlnsert = "INSERT INTO Customers (MembershipID, Contact, Email, Address, SurveyStatus, Subscription) VALUES"
             + " ('"+ member_ID + "', " + contact_num + ", '" + email_add + "', '" + mail_add + "' , " + radio_group + "," + receive_info + ")";

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a prepared statement where you can call setInt or setString method of preparedStatement class . so it will automatically remove string or numeric confusion at all.

BTW preparedStatement is the best way to pass parameter in sql query.don't use Statement class for parameter sql query.